# SageTeX: 1000sep for sage-calculated number (siunitx?)

Tags: siunitx, sagetex

How to add a '1000 sep' on i.e. `\sage{2^333}`?

[image]

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{sagetex}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\sisetup{group-separator = \text{\,}}

\begin{document}
Works:  \num{9000123}

\begin{sageblock}
x=2^333
\end{sageblock}

Works: \sage{x}

Works not: %\num{\sage{x}}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Compiling in `sagetex` is a 3 step process. The first step is LaTeX processing, second is Sage processing, the third is LaTeX processing. When you type `\sage{x}` imagine a ? is inserted for `\sage{x}` on the first step of compilation and after the 2nd step the ? is replaced with the Sage result for step 3. This is fundamentally different than `\num{\sage{x}}`because on step 1 of compilation you'll have `\num{?}` which LaTeX can't process because it needs to know what the ? is to compile. The approach of @John Palmieri solves most problems you'll encounter using `sagetex`

Comment: @DJP It is perfectly possible to design an interface for SageTeX that provides a macro which can yield Sage results in expansion-only contexts: see [my answer below](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/521389/73317). :-)

Comment: @frougon It's way over my head, dealing with expanding tokens and such. It's going to take me a lot of study to understand your interesting approach.

Comment: @DJP Expanding tokens is a core activity of TeX, it is quite happy chewing them. :-) I've added more examples at the end of the sample file to show why having an “expandable command” is convenient: you can use the results in *a lot* of places without doing anything special: `\mysageGetExpr` simply grabs its arguments and naturally expands to the result you asked for, wherever expansion hasn't been inhibited. BTW: a short definition of an “expandable command” could be: a macro that does its job correctly when used inside`\edef`.

Comment: `1000sep` is called `thousands separator` : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decimal_separator#Digit_grouping please edit your question

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## The problem

The `\sage` and `\sagestr` macros do many things at once, some of which are not “expandable” (actually, it is `\ST@sage` which does most of the work). This is exactly the same problem as with `\ref`, which is directly used by `\ST@sage`. Fortunately, there are ways to design an expandable interface in such cases; this is what packages such as `refcount` and `zref` do. The idea is simple:

1. In expansion-only contexts, you use an “expandable” command<sup>1</sup> to retrieve tokens associated to a reference which we'll call *foobar* here. This command may expand to various sequences of tokens based on test outcomes, but can't print error messages or perform assignments (except with LuaTeX, these things can't be done in expansion-only contexts). If the *foobar* reference you asked for is defined, the command *expands to the tokens associated with this reference* (in your case, that would be the result of a Sage computation).
2. In a place where you can do more than only-expanding-tokens, you use a second command to tell LaTeX that you have used reference *foobar*. Then, if LaTeX finds that reference *foobar* isn't defined (because for instance Sage hasn't been run yet in our case), it will remember and warn you at the end of the run that some references were undefined and you need to rerun something (here, Sage).

In our case, there is a third command needed before these two: the one that associates a macro of your choice—let's call it `\macro`—to a Sage expression so that the expression will be written to the `.sagetex.sage` file for later processing by Sage. Then you can use a call such as `\estGet{\macro}` to recover *in an expandable manner* the value of the expression computed by Sage. Here, `\estGet` is a macro from package `expsagetex`, which I wrote for this answer and makes it very easy to obtain the desired result.

## A solution with `expsagetex`

`expsagetex` is a LaTeX package available [here](https://github.com/frougon/expsagetex). It is a layer on top of `sagetex` that allows one to retrieve results from Sage in an expandable manner. I'll explain how to use it below, but you may want to begin with the *Quick start* section from [expsagetex.pdf](https://github.com/frougon/expsagetex/wiki/files/expsagetex.pdf) (source code [here](https://github.com/frougon/expsagetex/blob/master/doc/expsagetex.tex)). This is a file with a tutorial, many examples and explanations.

Using `expsagetex`, your problem can be solved as follows. Both sample files can be compiled with:

```
pdflatex document.tex
sage document.sagetex.sage
pdflatex document.tex
```

(alternatively, you may use `lualatex` or `xelatex`).

### Without automatic line wrapping

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{expsagetex}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\sisetup{group-separator = \,}

\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}

\begin{document}

With \verb|\estRecordFormatted|:\smallskip

\estRecordFormatted{\myIntRef}{2**233}%
\num{\estGet[-1]{\myIntRef}}%
\estRefUsed{\myIntRef}

\medskip
With \verb|\estRecordStr|:\smallskip

\estRecordFormatted{\myIntRefII}{str(2**233)}%
\num{\estGet[-1]{\myIntRefII}}%
\estRefUsed{\myIntRefII}

\end{document}
```

[image: Without automatic line wrapping]

In case you want to reuse your Python variable `x` defined by:

```latex
\begin{sageblock}
x = 2**333
\end{sageblock}
```

you can of course do so by replacing, e.g., `\estRecordFormatted{\myIntRef}{2**233}` with `\estRecordFormatted{\myIntRef}{x}`. This is because in the context where this matters, both `2**333` and `x` are Python expressions that evaluate to the same object: the integer you want to print.

### With automatic line wrapping

In case you want to have automatic line wrapping for the number, this can be done by not using `siunitx` and post-processing the number obtained from `expsagetex` in order to insert horizontal glue in the appropriate places. Here is a way to do so with `expl3`:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{expsagetex}
\usepackage{xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\regex_const:Nn \c_cis_regex { ( \cB\{ \c[LO]. \cE\} ){3} }
\tl_new:N \l_cis_tmpa_tl

\cs_generate_variant:Nn \tl_reverse_items:n { V }
\prg_generate_conditional_variant:Nnn \tl_if_eq:nn { Vx } { TF }

% #1: separator
% #2: “number”
\cs_new_protected:Npn \cis_seperate_thousands:nn #1#2
  {
    \tl_set:Nx \l_cis_tmpa_tl { \tl_reverse_items:n {#2} }
    \tl_set:Nn \l_tmpa_tl {#1}
    \regex_replace_all:NnN \c_cis_regex
      { \0 \cB\{ \u{\l_tmpa_tl} \cE\} } \l_cis_tmpa_tl
    \tl_set:Nx \l_cis_tmpa_tl { \tl_reverse_items:V \l_cis_tmpa_tl }

    \tl_if_eq:VxTF \c_space_tl { \tl_head:N \l_cis_tmpa_tl }
      { \tl_tail:N \l_cis_tmpa_tl }
      { \tl_use:N \l_cis_tmpa_tl }
  }

\cs_generate_variant:Nn \cis_seperate_thousands:nn { nx }

% The default separator (\,) is unbreakable.
\NewDocumentCommand \separateThousands { O{\,} m }
  { \cis_seperate_thousands:nx {#1} {#2} }

\NewDocumentCommand \thinbreakablespace { }
  { \hspace{.16667em plus 0.01em} }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}

\begin{document}

With \verb|\estRecordFormatted|:\smallskip

\estRecordFormatted{\myIntRef}{2**233}%
\separateThousands[\thinbreakablespace]{\estGet[-1]{\myIntRef}}%
\estRefUsed{\myIntRef}

\medskip
With \verb|\estRecordStr|:\smallskip

\estRecordFormatted{\myIntRefII}{str(2**233)}%
\separateThousands[\thinbreakablespace]{\estGet[-1]{\myIntRefII}}%
\estRefUsed{\myIntRefII}

\end{document}
```

[image: With automatic line wrapping]

Here too, you can use the `x` variable as input exactly in the same way as explained above.

## Using `expsagetex`

Here are explanations on how to use `expsagetex` that complement the currently available documentation ([expsagetex.pdf](https://github.com/frougon/expsagetex/wiki/files/expsagetex.pdf), [LaTeX source](https://github.com/frougon/expsagetex/blob/master/doc/expsagetex.tex)).

- The `\est*Record*` functions (`\est[GA]RecordStr`, `\est[GA]RecordFormatted` and `\est[GA]RecordFloat`) are all of the “third” kind of command described in the first part of this answer. Calling `\estRecordStr{\macro}{sage expression}` records `sage expression` in the `.sagetex.sage` file and associates the resulting output with `\macro`. After this, `\macro` will expand to an integer, but you don't need to know that. You'll need it to recover the value computed by Sage, by passing it to `\estGet`. You should also pass it to `\estRefUsed` (see below).
- These `\est*Record*` functions assign `\macro` locally, except those with a `G` in their name, which assign it globally.
- The `\est*Record*` functions with an `A` before `Record` in their name (A for “associative array”) accept two arguments instead of the single `\macro` argument. For instance, `\estARecordStr{base}{\whatever-\you-\want}{sage expression}` is equivalent to `\estRecordStr{\res}{sage expression}` where `\res` is the control sequence token obtained by expanding `\csname base@\whatever-\you-\want\endcsname` once.
- `\estRecordFormatted{\macro}{sage expression}` is similar to `\estRecordStr{\macro}{sage expression}`, except that it stores `latex(sage expression)` instead of just `sage expression` in the `.sagetex.sage` file. This may introduce math-mode commands in the LaTeX code obtained from `sagetex` if the result of evaluating `str(sage expression)` in Sage contains things such as exponents, brackets, etc.
- `\estRecordFloat{\macro}{sage expression}{format}` is for recording a floating point number in a particular format. For instance, if *format* is `.10f`, this will format the float as if you had issued `"%.10f" % (sage expression,)` in Python, i.e.: the result will be formatted with 10 decimal places and won't use exponent notation. If you need more flexibility, use `\estRecordStr` (if you need a percent sign for the Python code, you can use the `\percent` macro provided by `sagetex` or `expl3`'s `\c_percent_str` constant).
- `\estGet` is the command to retrieve a result in an expandable way. More precisely, `\estGet[fallback]{\macro}` ultimately expands to the result associated with `\macro` by one of the `\est*Record*` functions (the result is wrapped within `\exp_not:n`, aka `\unexpanded`). The first argument *fallback* is optional and used when the reference corresponding to `\macro` isn't defined yet (probably meaning that you need to run Sage on the .sagetex.sage file). This argument is particularly useful when you call `\estGet` in a place where the default, namely `??`, would cause an error (e.g., inside the mandatory argument of `siunitx`'s `\num` command).
- `\estRefUsed{\macro}` is what you should do to indicate that your code uses the result associated to `\macro`. This will generate the appropriate warning if the reference isn't defined yet, otherwise it won't do anything at all. You should use it whenever you have `\estGet[fallback]{\macro}` somewhere in your document. Since `\estRefUsed` is not expandable, you will often call `\estGet` and `\estRefUsed` in close vicinity, but not exactly in the same place. For instance:

  ```latex
  \estRecordFormatted{\mymacro}{2**5}  % record the expression 2**5
  \edef\myresult{\estGet[0]{\mymacro}} % store result in \myresult
  \estRefUsed{\mymacro}                % warn if it's not in the .sout file yet
  \show\myresult                       % show result on terminal
  ```

  In this example, it would not be correct to use `\estRecordFormatted` or `\estRefUsed` inside the `\edef`.

Of these macros, only `\estGet` is expandable (as well as its `expl3` sister `\est_get:nnn`). But this is the important one, the one you can use inside `\edef`, `\write`, `\fpeval`, `\num`, and many other places. For instance, if what it retrieves from Sage is of suitable type, you can use `\estGet` in the middle of an `\fpeval` calculation, in a counter or length (dimen or skip) register assignment, etc. You can even use it to compute the coordinates of many points in order to draw a plot with Ti*k*Z, `pgfplots` or any other TeX-based plotting framework. There are examples of all these things in [expsagetex.pdf](https://github.com/frougon/expsagetex/wiki/files/expsagetex.pdf); have a look at its [LaTeX source](https://github.com/frougon/expsagetex/blob/master/doc/expsagetex.tex). The possibilities are endless!

---

**Footnote**

1. In this answer, we say that a command is “expandable” if it does its job correctly when used inside `\edef`, i.e.: it expands to whatever it was designed to expand to, with no unwanted side effects. This property is often called “fully expandable”, but the terminology isn't really fixed. At least Heiko Oberdiek uses the term “expandable” with the same meaning as I am using here in some of his package manuals (IIRC), thus I feel relatively safe doing so. :-)

Comment: Wow, what a huge, but cool setup!

Comment: @OlegLobachev Thanks, glad you liked it. It takes a few lines but they are not terse as compared to typical TeX code, and due to the great expressiveness of `expl3`—thanks to variants, for one—many functions are just very simple one-liners.

Comment: @OlegLobachev You may want to reread the answer. I moved the code to a package (`expsagetex`) which has interesting improvements over the previous code and [more examples](https://github.com/frougon/expsagetex/wiki/files/expsagetex.pdf) ([source here](https://github.com/frougon/expsagetex/blob/master/doc/expsagetex.tex)), including dealing with Python lists and plotting with Ti*k*Z from Sage-computed coordinates. The new code has nice handing of floating point numbers, which were tricky to deal with using the previous code. I've tried to give better names to the functions, etc.

Answer (score 2):

This is a little clunky, but it works for me:

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{sagetex}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\sisetup{group-separator = \text{\,}}
\begin{document}

\begin{sageblock}
x=2^333
\end{sageblock}

\begin{sagesilent}
start="\\num{"
end="}"
\end{sagesilent}

Works: \sage{x}

Works, too: \sagestr{start+latex(x)+end}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Could we have this as a function like `numform(x)` or something like that?

Comment: I used `\newcommand\Num[1]{\ensuremath{\sagestr{start+latex(#1)+end}}}`