# How to execute SageTeX code multiple times with \loop?

Tags: loops, sagetex

I got the following errors when compiling the following MWE. How to fix it?

> Paragraph ended before `\verbatim@` was complete. ...

## First MWE

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{sagetex}


\newcount\i
\i=10


\begin{document}
\loop
%==================== BEGIN ===========================
\begin{sageblock}
    f(x) = exp(x) * sin(\i*x)
\end{sageblock}

The second derivative of $f$ is
\[
  \frac{\mathrm{d}^{2}}{\mathrm{d}x^{2}} \sage{f(x)} =
  \sage{diff(f, x, 2)(x)}.
\]

Here's a plot of $f$ from $-1$ to $1$:

\begin{center}
    \sageplot{plot(f, -1, 1)}
\end{center}
%=================== END ==============================
\advance \i -1
\ifnum \i>8
\repeat
\end{document}
```

## Second MWE

```
% secondMWE.tex
\documentclass[preview,border=12pt,12pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{sagetex}
\newcount\i
\i=10

\begin{document}
\loop
    \begin{preview}
        \sageplot[width=0.75\linewidth]{plot(sin(\the\i*x),x,0,2*pi)}
    \end{preview}
    \advance \i -1
    \ifnum \i>7
\repeat
\end{document}
```

[image]

The expected output shows 3 sine plots with different frequencies.

## Edit

Having read the existing answers, I come with the following idea which might be not difficult for TeX experts to implement. For the sake of simplicity, let me use the second MWE (`secondMWE.tex`).

The building process takes 4 steps instead of 3 steps.

- First, do `pdflatex secondMWE`, a new complete TeX file, for example `secondMWE_complete.tex`, is generated behind the scene. It contains something like

  ```
  % secondMWE_complete.tex
  \documentclass[preview,border=12pt,12pt]{standalone}
  \usepackage{sagetex}
  \begin{document}
  \begin{preview}
     \sageplot[width=0.75\linewidth]{plot(sin(10*x),x,0,2*pi)}
  \end{preview}
  \begin{preview}
     \sageplot[width=0.75\linewidth]{plot(sin(9*x),x,0,2*pi)}
  \end{preview}
  \begin{preview}
     \sageplot[width=0.75\linewidth]{plot(sin(8*x),x,0,2*pi)}
  \end{preview}
  \end{document}
  ```

  - Second, do `pdflatex secondMWE_complete`
  - Third, do `sage secondMWE_complete.sagetex.sage`
  - Fourth, do `pdflatex secondMWE_complete.tex` again

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I never bothered to learn the harder-than-Python-and-less-useful-than-Python-syntax so I'm not 100% sure but I don't think it's possible to mix with `sagetex` the way you are attempting without getting into `expl3` like was done in frougon's answer [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/521319/sagetex-1000sep-for-sage-calculated-number-siunitx/521389#521389), and that's way outside of what I know or want to learn. The problem you're up against is that compilation of LaTeX is a 3 stage process. First, LaTeX runs and essentially some space is set aside for where Sage calculations are needed. Second, Sage runs and the boxes are filled in. Third stage is that LaTeX is run on LaTeX plus Sage generated from the first two steps. That's creates the final document. When you use `\loop` it seems like you're assuming that LaTeX and Sage are working together so that `i` is getting passed to Sage and Sage keeps changing the functions based on a changing `i`. This is not following the 3 step compilation process so I see no way to make that work.

I would attempt to work completely in Python as follows:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{sagetex}
\begin{document}
%==================== BEGIN ===========================
\begin{sagesilent}
output = r""
for i in range(10,7,-1):
    f(x) = exp(x)*sin(i*x)
    output += r"The function is $f(x)= %s$."%(latex(f(x)))
    output += r" The second derivative of $f(x)$ is \[ \frac{\mathrm{d}^{2}}{\mathrm{d}x^{2}} %s = %s.\]"%(latex(f(x)),latex(diff(f, x, 2)(x)))
    output += r"Here's a plot of $f$ from $-1$ to $1$:\\"
    output += r"\begin{center}"
    output += r"\sageplot[width=8cm]{plot(%s,-1,1)}"%(f(x))
    output += r"\end{center}"
    output += r"\vspace{.15in}"
\end{sagesilent}
%=================== END ==============================
\sagestr{output}
\end{document}
```

The output in Cocalc is:
[image]

Note: 1. r"" is for raw strings which allows us to put in "bad" things like `\` without problems. The string is then built up as the loop runs. It's finally inserted completely with `\sagestr`. That means the first pass through the document is empty. The second pass through the string is created. The third pass through has the entire code which can go through LaTeX without a problem. 2. The use of `latex(f(x))` cleans up the presentation; for example, the multiplication symbols are gone. Try removing any `latex( )` from the code and you'll see the difference. 3. Finally, we can control the width of our plot to make the document look nicer; this was done with the option `[width=8cm]` in  `\sageplot`. It takes a little bit of time to adjust to working with strings but it solves most of the issues where `sagetex` is giving you problems.

Comment: I sometimes have problems with running code when I shouldn't. I delete all files but the .tex file and compile again. It seems like this forces the creation of .sage and .sout files which solves the problem. It's almost as if it uses the old files without recompiling.

Comment: Thank you  again.

Answer (score 2):

As DJP [explained](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/543469/73317), this is really difficult to do the way you want because `sageblock` uses some kind of `verbatim`, and the latter doesn't mix well at all with LaTeX code (by definition).

Just to show what can be done when one understands a bit the underlying mechanisms behind `verbatim`, though, here is a hacky way to make your first example work with your `\loop` construct. It's a mix of LaTeX2e style and `expl3` style because I started it in LaTeX2e but decided to use a convenient `expl3` trick in the end from an [answer by Bruno Le Floch](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/25753/73317).

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{sagetex}
\usepackage{xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\makeatletter

\NewDocumentEnvironment { mysageblock } { m +b }
  {
    \def\my@contents##1{#2}%
    \edef\my@tmpvalue{\number\csname #1\endcsname}%
    \edef\my@contents{%
      \unexpanded\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter{%
        \expandafter\my@contents\expandafter{\my@tmpvalue}}}%
    % Trick from <https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/25753/73317>
    \exp_args:Nx \scantokens
      {
        \token_to_str:N \begin{sageblock}
        \exp_not:V \my@contents
        \token_to_str:N \end{sageblock}
      }
  }
  { }

\makeatother
\ExplSyntaxOff

\newcount\i
\i=10

\begin{document}

\loop
%==================== BEGIN ===========================
\begin{mysageblock}{i}
    f(x) = exp(x) * sin(##1*x)
\end{mysageblock}

The second derivative of $f$ is
\[
  \frac{\mathrm{d}^{2}}{\mathrm{d}x^{2}} \sage{f(x)} =
  \sage{diff(f, x, 2)(x)}.
\]

Here's a plot of $f$ from $-1$ to $1$:

\begin{center}
    \sageplot{plot(f, -1, 1)}
\end{center}
%=================== END ==============================
\advance \i -1
\ifnum \i>8
\repeat

\end{document}
```

[image]

For the second example, since `sageplot` doesn't use `verbatim`, there is no such complication. Your code works as is for me. You can make the frequency changes more visible to convince yourself:

```latex
\documentclass[preview,border=12pt,12pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{sagetex}
\newcount\i
\i=3

\begin{document}
\loop
    \begin{preview}
        \sageplot[width=0.75\linewidth]{plot(sin(\the\i*x),x,0,2*pi)}
    \end{preview}
    \advance \i -1
    \ifnum \i>0
\repeat
\end{document}
```

[image]

Note: maybe you should avoid using single-letter variable names like `\i`, which normally is for typesetting a dotless i.

Comment: You're welcome. I've removed a harmless but unneeded group.

Comment: AFAICT, your second example works as is. No such complication appears to be needed (see my update).

Comment: My pleasure. I added a missing pair of braces in the first piece of code that was causing the `\makeatother` to be silently eaten (it's easy to forget, because when using a `b` argument type with `\NewDocumentEnvironment`, the end part of the definition isn't useful; moreover, `\NewEnviron` from the `environ` package has no end part for this very reason).